# Can you take nine dyads for the dyad base?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, education

$\vec{e^k} \otimes \vec{e^l} (k,l = 1,2,3) $

I do not understand how to prove that this can be taken for nine dyads.
Is there a version to use $\vec{e_i} \otimes \vec{e^k} (i,k = 1,2,3)$, or the correct course of thought?

Comment: This is fairly [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Three-dimensional_Euclidean_space),

Comment: @KurtG. sorry i didn't understand you

Comment: @KurtG. I just need to derive this formula, I do not understand how

Comment: The nine dyads you are looking for are written down in that Wikipedia article using the notation $\mathbf{ii},...,\mathbf{kk}$. You need to derive what formula ?

Comment: @KurtG. this formula $\vec{e^k} \otimes \vec{e^l} (k,l = 1,2,3) $

Comment: Represent $\vec{e^k}$ as the $k$-th canonical basis vector of $\mathbb R^3$. Then $\vec{e^k}\otimes \vec{e^l}$ is the Kronecker product. For example, 
$$
\vec{e^1}\otimes \vec{e^2}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$

Comment: @KurtG. oo understand, thank you